# Using Tomcat Context Resource to define JDBC connection: Hiding connection credentials

Tags: java, tomcat, jdbc, apache-commons-dbcp

I just finished setting up my web application (deployed on Tomcat) to use Apache Commons DBCP2 to connect to Postgres.  Database credentials are specified in a Resource tag of the context.xml like that:

```
<Context>
    <Resource name="jdbc/postgres" auth="Container"
        type="javax.sql.DataSource" driverClassName="org.postgresql.Driver"
        url="jdbc:postgresql://127.0.0.1:5432/postgres"
        username="my-user-name" password="my-password"
        initialSize="1" maxTotal="20" minIdle="1" maxIdle="5"
        .../>
</Context>
```

and I get the Connection in the usual manner:

```
DataSource ds = (DataSource)(new InitialContext().lookup("java:/comp/env/jdbc/postgres"));
Connection conn = ds.getConnection();
```

The problem is that I cannot go like that to production, with the database credentials explicitly specified in the xml file.

I saw that `DataSource` interface has a method for `getConnection(user, password)` but `BasicDataSource` implementation does not support this operation (thorws UnsupportedOperationException)

How do you make a DBCP config production-ready?

Comment: server.xml based Resource is widely used in Production and it is deemed secure enough and production ready. You might need to store username and password in a file anyway if you need to allow flexibility in your application. Resource is one of the most secure way.

Comment: The solution to this is ultimately physical security of the server, with access cards, logging, and all that.

Comment: @shazin is correct that this is widely used and you are left relying on app server security to protect your database. Just because it is widely used doesn't make it right or sufficient. I would point out that such lax security methodologies have made data breaches an industry standard.

Comment: There is a good example here (http://www.jdev.it/encrypting-passwords-in-tomcat/) on how to create a datasource with passwords that are encrypted in your context.xml. You would not have to store clear text passwords in files.

Comment: @ramp - thanks for the link.  For the benefit of future readers I will summerize: the suggested solution is to write a custom DataSourceFactory which accepts encrypted credentials and is able to decrypt them when creating DataSources.  This is a valid solution.  However, it has two problems:

Comment: 1) all encryption algorithms need an unencrypted String password/passphrase/secret-key themselves.  There is one also present in the presented solution (search for defaultSecretKey to find it) this is only mildly better than hardcoding the password in a Java file.

Comment: 2) according to a comment, some of the code in the custom DataSourceFactory is copied from Tomcat's class (that is also the super class) and that brings up the usual problem of the code becoming obsolete in future versions of Tomcat

Comment: @Sharon, you are right on all counts and it has been pointed out in other posts here as well. This is just a way to get away from storing the password in clear text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to protect your database credentials (or any secret, for that matter), you need to ensure that the keys to the kingdom are never digitally stored in such a manner that someone can access them. If the bad guy gets root access to an app server, if the DB credentials are stored in a clear-text file he can get to your data.

That means that you either need to store the credentials in an encrypted file. Of course, the running app needs to recover the credentials and therefore needs the passphrase to the encrypted file. Obviously the passphrase cannot be stored or you have not increased security at all.

The conclusion I have come to is that you need to have at least one piece of information (call it a passphrase) that is never stored anywhere. Whoever starts the server needs to know and provide the passphrase (via some safe channel, such as an HTTPS POST) to the application.

Of course, the running app needs to have the credentials in clear-text in memory to actually access the database, so you are still vulnerable to an attack that gets access to the server and scrapes the live memory of the server. But such an attack is significantly harder than reading files on the file system.

I don't know of any existing open source framework that supports this kind of functionality in Tomcat. I have built a home grown solution that we use for our applications, so I know it is possible to do. The details of how you would design/implement this will probably be dependent on how you want to run your system in production.

Once you buy into a different approach, you might find other significant benefits. For example, because we dynamically manage the DB credentials we are able to change the DB password whenever we want to, without restarting the app servers or interrupting service.

Comment: I guess this gives me a full answer (although not the one I was hoping for), thanks